# Jquery if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a form which allows the user to input their own custom values for a simple online ‘thermostat’ (Minimum Temperature, Maximum Temperature and PowerSaver Maximum Temperature).

I am trying to write some jquery such that when the user submits the form with the custom values, it sets the custom values, and also changes the text to show the user which changes they made (e.g. `“You've changed your minimum temperature to 5”`)

Currently, only the first form field ‘minimum temperature’ is working, and setting the correct value. The other two aren’t working as expected.

In addition, I’d like the user to be able to set all the custom values at once (one form submission), and for the following statements to appear on screen simultaneously  e.g.:

> You've changed your minimum temperature to 5 
>   You've changed your maximum temperature to 50  
>   You've changed your power saver maximum temperature to 30

The above statements should only show if the user has entered a value on that field. i.e. if the user has only entered a value for the maximum temperature, it should only show the following statement:

> You've changed your maximum temperature to 50

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated. Thanks very much in advance!

Code for the form:

```
    <form id="custom-values">
        <input type="text" id="mintemperature" placeholder="Minimum temperature">
        <input type="text" id="maxtemperature" placeholder="Maximum temperature">
        <input type="text" id="maxtemperatureps" placeholder="Max. PowerSaver temperature">
        <input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Set!">
    </form>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('#custom-values').on('submit', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

            if ($('#mintemperature').val() !== "") {
            $('#message').text("You've changed your minimum temperature to " + $('#mintemperature').val())
            thermostat.minTemperature = parseInt($('#mintemperature').val())
            }
            if ($('#maxtemperature').val() !== "") {
            $('#message').text("You've changed your maximum temperature to " + $('#maxtemperature').val())
            thermostat.minTemperature = parseInt($('#mintemperature').val())
            }
            if ($('#maxtemperatureps').val() !== "") {
            $('#message').text("You've changed your power saver maximum temperature to " + $('#maxtemperatureps').val())
            thermostat.minTemperature = parseInt($('#mintemperature').val())
            }
        });
```

Comment: `thermostat.minTemperature = parseInt($('#mintemperature').val())` three times? To me sounds like it's time to take a break! :)

Comment: "The other two aren’t working as expected." What *is* expected? And *how* do they fail?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - rookie error! It had been a very long day indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is:

```js
$('#custom-values').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // creating an object to define what setting is associated
  // with each element (identified by its id as the key):
  var messages = {
    'mintemperature' : 'minimum',
    'maxtemperature' : 'maximum',
    'maxtemperatureps' : 'maximum power-saving'
  },
  // creating an array, using map and get, of the nodes that have
  // had their values changed from the default, and whose value can
  // be parsed as a number (in base 10):
      changes = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').map(function () {
    if ( this.value !== this.defaultValue && parseInt(this.value, 10)) {
      return this;
    }
  }).get(),
  // creating an '<li>' element as a jQuery object:
      li = $('<li />'),
  // creating a variable to hold a clone within the (later) forEach:
      clone;
  // empty out existing messages:
  $('#messages').empty();
  // iterate over the array of changed nodes:
  changes.forEach(function (changed) {
    // cloning the created jQuery <li> object:
    clone = li.clone();
    // setting its html to the following concatenated string:
    clone.html('You have changed the ' + messages[changed.id] + ' temperature setting, to: ' + changed.value + '&deg;C')
    // appending the <li> to the '#messages' element:
    .appendTo('#messages');
  });
  
  
  
});
```

```css
#messages {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
/* hiding the #messages element if it has
   no content (including white-space): */
#messages:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="custom-values">
  <input type="text" id="mintemperature" placeholder="Minimum temperature">
  <input type="text" id="maxtemperature" placeholder="Maximum temperature">
  <input type="text" id="maxtemperatureps" placeholder="Max. PowerSaver temperature">
  <input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Set!">
</form>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
```

References:

- [`appentTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appentTo/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer - it’s been extremely helpful! The only thing that I don’t think it addressed is actually changing the value of the thermostat itself:

  thermostat.minTemperature = parseInt($('#mintemperature').val())
  thermostat.maxTemperature = parseInt($('#maxtemperature').val())
  thermostat.maxTemperaturePowerSaver = parseInt($('#maxtemperatureps').val())

This is probably because the code that I posted on my question initially was slightly incorrect and didn’t include 2 of the above 3 lines (it had been a long day!). I’m going to figure out how to do this now.